# Сокрытие кода с#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я написал программу и не хочу, чтобы обычные пользователи могли смотреть код, менять его и т.д. Скажи, может кто-нибудь знает, как это реализовать, а то я не знаю даже с какой стороны подойти к этому?

Comment: обычные и так не могут смотреть код, а от необычных - никак не закроешься

Comment: вам нужна [обфускация](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%81%23&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: а почему Вы считаете что Ваш *код* кому то нужен?! если он действительно такой крутой, то **максимум**, Вы сможете усложнить жизнь, желающим его получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна обфускация

[C# Source Code Obfuscator](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscator.html)

[Eazfuscator](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net)

[AppFuscator](http://appfuscator.com/)

Но если речь идет только об обфускации исходного кода, то должно бы хватить C# Source Code Obfuscator.